# Having text show on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm trying to have a background image disappear and then have some text appear in the div with a link.  I've gotten the image to disappear on mouseover but I can't get the text to display.  Here is what I've got so far.  I'm kinda new to this stuff.

```
/* I'm have the image removed with the first line, then setting the link
   as hidden then trying to make it visible, but the link never shows */

$('#res').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('resume');
  $('#reslink').css(visibility,visible);
});
```

HTML:

```
        <div id = "res" class = "floatleft squares resume"><a id = "reslin" class = "link" href="resume.php">link</a></div>
  <div id = "pro" class = "floatleft squares projects"><a id = "prolin" class = "link" href="projects.php"></a></div>
  <div id = "con" class = "floatleft squares contact"><a id = "conlin" class = "link" href="contact.php"></a></div>
  <div id = "abo" class = "floatleft squares about"><a id = "abolin" class = "link" href="about.php"></a></a></div>
```

Styles:

```
a{
 display: block;
 background: grey;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%; 
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

If any more info is needed, lmk, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#reslink').css(visibility,visible)
```

try

```
$('#reslin').css('visibility','visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a typo: `#reslink` or `#reslin`?

Answer (score 0):

Your id on the anchor is "reslin" not "reslink"

Try this:

```
 $('#reslin').css("visibility", "visible");
 or
 $('#reslin').css("display", "block");
```